# SQLException: Cannot submit statement in current context

Tags: jdbc, prepared-statement, callable-statement, voltdb

I encountered this exception when calling a stored procedure through a prepared statement, however, it works for callable statement. I am wondering if it is a must to use callable statement for invoking a stored procedure in voltdb?

```
String sql = "{call get_city_by_country(?)}";
PreparedStatement stat = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
stat.setString(1, "china");
ResultSet results = stat.executeQuery();
```

Throws exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Cannot submit statement in current context: '{call get_city_by_country(?)};'.
at org.voltdb.jdbc.SQLError.get(SQLError.java:45)
at org.voltdb.jdbc.JDBC4PreparedStatement.executeQuery(JDBC4PreparedStatement.java:121)
```

This one works fine.

```
CallableStatement proc = conn.prepareCall(sql);
proc.setString(1, "china");
ResultSet results = proc.executeQuery();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It look like your driver only supports the `CALL` escape on `CallableStatement`. So you need to use `CallableStatement` instead.

Section 6.4 *Java EE JDBC Compliance* of the JDBC 4.2 specification however says (empasis mine):

> Drivers must support stored procedures. The `DatabaseMetaData` method
>   `supportsStoredProcedures` must return `true`. **The driver must also support
>   the full JDBC API escape syntax for calling stored procedures** with the following methods **on the `Statement`, `PreparedStatement`, and `CallableStatement` classes**:
>
> - `executeUpdate`
> - `executeQuery`
> - `execute`

This means that your driver is not fully compliant with the Java EE JDBC Compliance requirements. You might want to consider filing a bug report with the driver vendor.

Comment: Awesome. This is what I want to find out. Thank you very much.